# Using a separate .fla file as a MovieClip in a larger project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, movieclip

Just to preface: I haven't used Flash in a long long time, however, I am still aware of the environment.

Backstory: I created a small .fla to perform actions on a MovieClip on the stage (in my case, a health/HP bar). I made the health effect using a Document Class (HealthBar.as).

The question: What I'm trying to figure out now is how, in a totally separate .fla, to create multiple instances of these health bars and be able to access the methods in Document Class HealthBar.as from the Document Class in this new .fla

If I am doing this incorrectly in the first place, feel free to yell at me, and let me know how doing something like this SHOULD have been done.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should be able to import/reference the compiled SWF with the assets for your `HealthBar` class into the new FLA. But I’m not sure how simple that is with a document class, as I’ve usually created plain asset libraries (SWFs with no logic) with AS3 classes that embedded those then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're halfway there with a document class.  Now you just need to make it into a proper class in your com.domain.className (or drop the .as file into the same directory as your fla).  While creating classfiles is trivial, online examples seem to muck it up, so [here's Adobe's official demo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000182.html) (*bleh*).

That said, creating more healthbars basically looks like this...

**Class**

```
package {
    public class HealthBar extends Sprite {
        public function HealthBar() {
            // constructor
            trace("Healthbar created")
        }
    }
}
```

**Document Code**

```
import HealthBar;

for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var randomHealthBar:HealthBar = new HealthBar(); // <-- magic sauce
    addChild(randomHealthBar);
}

// traces: "Healthbar created" 10 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to copy the movieclip from the healthbar .fla into your main .fla and then give it an actionscript linkage of HealthBar?

Then you should be able to call new HealthBar whenever you need one in your main file.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing - but I thought there should be a better way.